# When scrolling, the cursor follows the scroll instead of staying in a field on iOS?

Tags: ios, scroll, sencha-touch-2, text-cursor

I develop a hybrid mobile application with Sencha Touch (only HTML5, CSS and JavaScript).

When I want to edit a text field, I tap on it and the iOS keyboard is displayed. However, when I scroll in the form, the cursor of the field follows the scroll instead of staying in the field.

Is anyone know how to fix this issue?

P.S.: the version of iOS is 6.1 and 7.
P.S. 2: the issue is not present with Android.

Comment: Please see the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/39797084/1233916.  The gist of that approach is to use Javascript to change the value of the input and then revert the change.  Updating the field value triggers iOS to bring the caret back into the field.

Answer (score 1):

It apears this is a Safari Webkit issue and has been filed as a bug for iOS 7 and 8

[Mobile Safari - Input caret does not scroll along with overflow-scrolling: touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20737503/mobile-safari-input-caret-does-not-scroll-along-with-overflow-scrolling-touch)