# Input caret floating over a fixed layer when scrolling

Tags: ios, scroll, uiwebview, mobile-safari

[image]

In iOS Safari, when we have a fixed header and scrollable content under it, when we scroll, the input is properly hidden by the header but the blinking cursor remains over it.

Reproduced in iOS 9.2.1 and 9.3 beta

Here is the code, to test in iOS safari
[http://jsbin.com/hoxuxu/edit?html,css,js,output]

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/20737503/1061602

Comment: @AdamMarshall Not exactly the same but probably related. This happens with `overflow: auto`